# Looking for help to another onEdit to the original script to include a time stamp generating

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I have 2 onEdit Script one for the check box to move to different sheet and the other timestamp, I was looking to combine both of them and revise it according to differents requirements

Check Box Script:

```
The requirements when the check box in column 15 is true the data will transfer to AM2 and a check box will created in Column 17 and when the last is true the row will move to sheet Done
```

```
    function onEdit(event) {
      // assumes source data in sheet named main
      // target sheet of move to named Completed
      // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to colu 15 or o
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
      var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

      if(s.getName() == "AM1" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == true) {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("AM2");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
        s.deleteRow(row);
      } else if(s.getName() == "AM2" && r.getColumn() == 17 && r.getValue() == true) {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DONE");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
        s.deleteRow(row);
      }
    }
```

```
the goal from the above timestamp will be generated in sheet AM1 column 14 once column 15 is true and again will be generated in column 16 once column 17 is true
```

TimeStamp:

```
const onEdit = (e) => {         
if(e.range.columnStart === 14 && e.range.rowStart > 2)         
{         
if(e.range.getSheet().getName() === 'AM1' , 'AM2' ) {          
const oSet = e.range.offset(0,-2)         
e.value ? oSet.setValue(new Date()) : oSet.clearContent()         
}         
}         
}   



A sample of the sheet is here :
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qfkCR5N97CfePTiV8R-RYdyHpPla6KxqxrkN-iDi6IA/edit#gid=417345635

looking forwards to your kind help and advice if possible.

```
Thanks, 
Adabsiz
```

Comment: i did some editing on the script am unable to paste it, one of the issue that am facing now is when i check the box in AM1 the row transfer directly yo DONE sheet not to AM2 which suppose to be

Comment: About `I have 2 onEdit Script one for the check box to move to different sheet and the other timestamp`, when I saw your sample Spreadsheet, I found `check box`. But, I cannot find `timestamp`. Where can I find it? And, about `The requirements when the check box in column 15 is true the data will transfer to AM2 and a check box will created in Column 17 and when the last is true the row will move to sheet Done `, what is `the last`?

Comment: @Tanaike, the timestamp will generate when the check box will tick, that's what am looking to achieve

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- When the checkbox of the column "O" is checked, you want to put the timestamp to the column "N".
- When the checkbox of the column "Q" is checked, you want to put the timestamp to the column "P".
- You want to run above situation for the sheets of `AM1` and `AM2`.
- And also, you want to merge your current `onEdit` script shown in your upper script of question.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var obj = {"AM1": {col: 15, dst: "AM2"}, "AM2": {col: 17, dst: "DONE"}};

  var ss = e.source;
  var r = e.range;
  var s = r.getSheet();
  var sheetName = s.getSheetName();
  var o = obj[sheetName];
  if (o && o.col == r.columnStart) {
    if (r.isChecked()) {
      r.offset(0, -1).setValue(new Date());
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(o.dst);
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      if (sheetName == "AM1") {
        var dstRange = target.offset(0, 16);
        r.copyTo(dstRange);
        dstRange.uncheck();
      }
      var row = r.getRow();
      s.getRange(row, 1, 1, s.getLastColumn()).moveTo(target);
      s.deleteRow(row);
    } else {
      r.offset(0, -1).clearContent();
    }
  }
}
```

- In this script,

  - When the checkbox of the column "O" of "AM1" sheet is checked, the timestamp is put to the column "N" and the row is moved to the next row of the last row of "AM2" sheet, and put the unchecked checkbox to the column "Q".
  - When the checkbox of the column "Q" of "AM2" sheet is checked, the timestamp is put to the column "P" and the row is moved to the next row of the last row of "DONE" sheet.

#### Note:

- About, the scripts for `When the checkbox of the column "O" is checked, you want to put the timestamp to the column "N".` and `When the checkbox of the column "Q" is checked, you want to put the timestamp to the column "P".`, when this is reflected to the script, it becomes as follows.

  ```
    const onEdit = (e) => {
      const range = e.range;
      if (['AM1', 'AM2'].includes(range.getSheet().getSheetName()) && (range.columnStart === 15 || range.columnStart === 17) && range.rowStart > 1) {
        const oSet = range.offset(0, -1);
        if (range.isChecked()) {
          oSet.setValue(new Date());
        } else {
          oSet.clearContent();
        }
      }
    }
  ```

  - In this script, at first, the sheet is checked using `['AM1', 'AM2'].includes(range.getSheet().getSheetName())`. And, the column number and the row number are checked. And, when the checkbox is checked, the timestamp is put to the neighbour cell to the left of active cell. When the checkbox is unchecked, the neighbour cell to the left of active cell is cleared.

#### References:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [isChecked()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#ischecked)